# Python Pandas: Append Dataframe To Another Dataframe Only If Column Value is Unique

Tags: python, pandas, append, conditional-statements

I have two data frames that I want to append together.  Below are samples.

df_1:

```
Code    Title
103     general checks 
107     limits
421     horseshoe
319     scheduled 
501     zonal
```

df_2

```
Code    Title
103     hello 
108     lucky eight 
421     little toe 
319     scheduled cat
503     new item
```

I want to append df_2 to df_1 ONLY IF the code number in df_2 does not exist already in df_1.

Below is the dataframe I want:

```
Code    Title
103     general checks 
107     limits
421     horseshoe
319     scheduled 
501     zonal 
108     lucky eight 
503     new item
```

I have searched through Google and Stackoverflow but couldn't find anything on this specific case.

Answer (score 6):

Just [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) the filtered data frame

```
df3 = df2.loc[~df2.Code.isin(df.Code)]
df.append(df3)

    Code    Title
0   103 general checks
1   107 limits
2   421 horseshoe
3   319 scheduled
4   501 zonal
1   108 lucky eight
4   503 new item
```

Notice that you might end up with duplicated indexes, which may cause problems. To avoid that, you can `.reset_index(drop=True)` to get a fresh df with no duplicated indexes.

```
df.append(df3).reset_index(drop=True)

    Code    Title
0   103 general checks
1   107 limits
2   421 horseshoe
3   319 scheduled
4   501 zonal
5   108 lucky eight
6   503 new item
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `concat` and then `drop_duplicates`. Assumes within each dataframe `Code` is unique.

```
res = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('Code')

print(res)

   Code           Title
0   103  general_checks
1   107          limits
2   421       horseshoe
3   319       scheduled
4   501           zonal
1   108     lucky_eight
4   503        new_item
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to concat(), you could also use merge:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='outer').drop_duplicates('Code')

    Code    Title
0   103 general checks
1   107 limits
2   421 horseshoe
3   319 scheduled
4   501 zonal
6   108 lucky eight
9   503 new item
```